# Mutate to calculate mean of multiple columns without typing them out

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to take the rowwise mean of 54 columns containing `NA` values without having to spell out each column, i.e., I want to use `:` to select the columns I want to use:

```
data1 <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(m = mean(c(A1:C3), na.rm=T))
```

When I do that, however, I get the following error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `m = mean(c(A1:C3), na.rm = T)`.
i In row 2.
Caused by error in `A1:C3`:
! NA/NaN argument
```

Apparently the `na.rm = T` argument wasn't accounted for? It works if I spell out all the columns, i.e.,

```
data1 <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(m = mean(c(A1, B1, C1, D1, ...), na.rm=T))
```

But that's very tedious and I don't want to write out 54 column names if I don't have to. Any ideas for accomplishing this in the `tidyverse` world? Here's the reprex:

```
data <- structure(list(SampleID = c(5, 6), StationID = c("ROC", "DAK"
), Date = structure(c(1127361600, 1347336000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), A1 = c(100, 50), B1 = c(100, 10), C1 = c(100, 
30), D1 = c(100, 10), E1 = c(100, 0), F1 = c(60, 20), G1 = c(60, 
100), H1 = c(0, 10), I1 = c(40, 10), J1 = c(40, 10), K1 = c(100, 
30), L1 = c(40, 20), M1 = c(40, 10), N1 = c(40, 10), O1 = c(100, 
100), P1 = c(100, 0), Q1 = c(80, 10), R1 = c(100, NA), S1 = c(60, 
10), T1 = c(100, 100), U1 = c(70, 10), V1 = c(70, 10), W1 = c(100, 
100), X1 = c(100, 30), Y1 = c(80, 30), Z1 = c(30, 10), A2 = c(20, 
20), B2 = c(60, 100), C2 = c(30, 50), D2 = c(100, 10), E2 = c(20, 
0), F2 = c(30, 0), G2 = c(20, 30), H2 = c(30, 30), I2 = c(100, 
60), J2 = c(0, 10), K2 = c(20, 100), L2 = c(100, 40), M2 = c(100, 
40), N2 = c(100, 100), O2 = c(50, NA), P2 = c(20, NA), Q2 = c(40, 
NA), R2 = c(40, NA), S2 = c(100, NA), T2 = c(30, NA), U2 = c(30, 
NA), V2 = c(100, NA), W2 = c(100, NA), X2 = c(100, NA), Y2 = c(100, 
NA), Z2 = c(50, NA), A3 = c(50, NA), B3 = c(50, NA), C3 = c(100, 
NA)), row.names = 5:6, class = "data.frame")
```

Also note that the column names here are ones I invented using `c(paste0(LETTERS[1:26], "1"), paste0(LETTERS[1:26], "2"), paste0(LETTERS[1:3], "3")`, they are not the column names of my og data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `c_across()`. Inside `c_across()`, you can use tidyselect selection, like `starts_with()`, `:`, `where()`, etc. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/c_across.html?q=c_acr#ref-usage

Here it is:

```r
data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(m = mean(c_across(A1:C3))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

If you have NAs, you can use na.rm = TRUE in the mean function, like so.

```r
data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(m = mean(c_across(A1:C3), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

For a better speed, this is true only for means and sums, there is the base R function rowMeans(), rowSums() that allows you to avoid the rowwise call, hence increased speed. You can use the `pick()` function inside.

```r
data |>
  mutate(
    m = rowMeans(pick(A1:C3), na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

Comment: Beautiful, didn't know about the `c_across()` function! Will accept the answer in a couple minutes when it lets me. Thanks so much!

Comment: I added another solution that doesn't require the c_across and rowwise, but uses pick instead. For row means and row sums, it is much faster than the c_across alternative.

Comment: I always love the fastest way to do something, so I'll use this. Thanks again very much!